# Strange behavior of custom (with withStyle) controlled material-ui TextField

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I am trying to use a Material-ui TextField in a form.
This Textfield is controlled in a way that only hexadecimal characters are authorized.

```
<form style={{ flex: '1' }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField margin='normal' label="Base address" size="small" variant="outlined" fullWidth
          InputProps={{ startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">0x</InputAdornment> }}
          helperText="Please enter 8 hexadecimal digits"
          value={this.state.address}
          onChange={event => {
            if (/^[0-9A-Fa-f]*$/.test(event.target.value))
              this.setState({ address: event.target.value })
            else this.setState({ address: this.state.address })
          }}
        />
</form>
```

This is working as expected, no problem.
But when I replace the TextField by my custom one called CssTextField

```
const CssTextField = withStyles({
      root: {
        '& label': {
          color: 'var(--input-foreground)',
          '&.Mui-focused': {
            color: 'var(--inputValidation-infoBorder)',
          },
        },
        '& input': {
          color: 'var(--input-foreground)',
        },
        '& input:invalid + fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'var(--inputValidation-errorBorder)',
        },

        '& .MuiFormHelperText-contained': {
          color: 'var(--input-foreground)',
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: 'var(--input-foreground)',
        },

        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'var(--thinput-foreground)',
          },
          '& fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'var(--input-foreground)',
          },
          '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderColor: 'var(--inputValidation-infoBorder)',
          },
          '& p.MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary': {
            color: 'var(--input-foreground)',
          },
        },
      },
    })(TextField);
```

The new style is applied but the behavior (not only the style) of the CssTextField changes compared to TextField.
Indeed, once I enter a simple character, the focus is lost from the CssTextField and I need to click again in the field to enter a new character... which is of course not happening with the "normal" TextField.

BTW this weird behavior does not occur when I remove the control (remove props value & onChange) when using the CssTextField.

So I am in a situation where I can control the input but not the style, or I can style the TextField but not control the input !

Additional info: even with an empty style (setting only root:{} in withStyles) the issue occurs.

Any suggestions is more than welcome.
Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you are defining `CssTextField` inside another component rather than at the top level. You need to move the declaration of `CssTextField` to the top level (i.e. not nested inside of another function/component). When defined within another component, it gets redefined with each render of the containing component resulting in a new component type. This causes the CssTextField element to be remounted (old element completely removed from the DOM and new element added to the DOM) rather than just re-rendered so focus is lost as the element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I modified my code in the way you suggested. It's working as expected now. Thanks for your support.